# python-vlc - Codec `h264' (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) is not supported

Tags: python, libvlc, python-vlc

I am trying to play a video using python-vlc in python. It is giving me the following error.

```
[00007f92180098b0] main decoder error: Codec `h264` (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) is not supported.
[00007f92180098b0] main decoder error: Codec not supported
[00007f92180098b0] main decoder error: VLC could not decode the format "h264" (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10))
```

The code to play the video is as follows

```
import sys
import vlc
import easygui

if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print("Please enter file name as command line argument")
    exit(0)

media = vlc.MediaPlayer(sys.argv[1])
media.play()
while True:
    pass
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Same issue. Ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I came across with this problem while using Anaconda virtual environment. I solved it by updating `ffmpeg` package which was very old. This action also triggered `openh264` new library installation.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

In case of the usual `python` run, I think installing/updating ffmpeg library will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libavcodec by running `apt install libavcodec58` and make sure the system VLC player can play the MP4 file without any errors.

If you are running Anaconda Python, some old-version Anaconda Python will cause the H264-codec-not-found error. So try to install the latest version Anaconda or Miniconda, and use its `pip` to install `python-vlc` and launch Python VLC.